# How to get result set in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do the following in hibernate:

```
Session session2 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
List<TitleEntity> tt = session2.createQuery(
  "select * from title where url = 'http://google.com'
").getResultList();
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from title where url = 'http://google.com']
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
```

What would be the correct way to get `SELECT *` as a result set?

Answer (score 1):

In HQL you don't specify the `*` character, in fact you don't need to specify `select` unless you want to only return a portion of the query.  Also you need to reference the entity name specifically.  So removing `select *` and updating the entity name fixes your query:

```
from TitleEntity where url = 'http://google.com'
```

The error indicates the 8th column being the culprit, this directly indicates the `*` character of the query.

For reference: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Comment: thanks, and the table name is the Entity name and not the actual sql table name.

Comment: Ah, figured you overrode the name... will update the answer.